# How can I solve this build error: "no matching function for call to" in C++ under UNIX?

Tags: c++, unix, build

How can I solve this build error: "no matching function for call to" in C++ under UNIX?

I am getting the following build error:

```
unixserver:Lab1> make
g++ -o LSL lab1.cpp Employee.cpp
lab1.cpp: In function int main():
lab1.cpp:199: error: no matching function for call to LinkedSortedList<Employee>::find(std::string&)
LinkedSortedList.cpp:137: note: candidates are: bool LinkedSortedList<Elem>::find(Elem) const [with Elem = Employee]
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Here is my find function:

```
// Check to see if "value" is in the list.  If it is found in the list,
// return true, otherwise return false.  Like print(), this function is
// declared with the "const" keyword, and so cannot change the contents
// of the list.
template<class Elem>
bool LinkedSortedList<Elem>::find(Elem searchvalue) const {
         if (head == NULL) {
                 return false;
         } else {
                 while (head != NULL) {
                    LinkedNode<Elem>* pointer;
                    for (pointer = head; pointer != NULL; pointer = pointer->next) 
                        if (pointer->value == searchvalue) {
                            return true;
                        }
                  }
         }
         return false;
 }
```

And this is in my LinkedSortedList.h file under the "public:" section:

```
bool find(Elem searchvalue) const;
```

Here is the missing code: line 199

```
                        case 'S':
                                cout << "Save database to a file selected\n\n";
                                // TODO call function to save database to file
                                // File I/O Save to file
                                cout << "Please enter a file name: " << endl;
                                cin >> fileName;
                                {char* file = (char*) fileName.c_str();
                                writeFile(file, database);}
                                break;
```

Comment: Please don't post line numbers in your code like this; it makes it very difficult for anyone to copy and paste into an editor.

Comment: Also, you haven't posted the code that's causing the error (i.e. line 199 and any other relevant lines above it).

Comment: Please format your code.  And the compiler output example.

Comment: I posted the missing code, sorry about that.

Comment: How do you format code when making a post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, as the error message states, that you are trying to invoke this function:

```
LinkedSortedList::find(std::string&)
```

but it doesn't exist.

You have three options:

1. Create that function. In the `public` section of `LinkedSortedList` declare (and subsequently implement) something like `find(const std::string&)`;
2. Don't invoke that function. In your test program, call `list.find(elem)` instead of `list.find(str)`, for example.
3. Make `Employee` implicitly constructable from `std::string`. Add a new public constructor to `Employee` that takes a single `std::string` as a parameter.